# Adding more files in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I am looking for small help,

Consider I have two views "`master_code_view"` and "`testing_may_rel_view`"

I have copied all my code in `master_code_view` and using config spec able to locate the same code in my second view too.
Every 2 months, I need to add new files and directories in "`master_code_view`" whereas I am unable to find those files and directories in "`testing_may_rel_view`".

How to replicate only those new files and also it shouldn't affect other files in "`testing_may_rel_view`"?

My config Spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../testing/LATEST
element * REL_TESTING_JUNE -mkbranch testing
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch testing
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `testing` branch just for visualization (of a certain state of the `master` branch), then you can simply

- add a new tag (`REL_TESTING_JULY`) in the `master` branch after importing your new files (label the new files and directory only)
- update the config spec of your second view `testing_may_rel_view` in order to see that label.

As in:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../testing/LATEST
element * REL_TESTING_JULY -mkbranch testing
element * REL_TESTING_JUNE -mkbranch testing
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch testing
```

---

If you do some development in testing, then I would recommend merging `master` to `testing`.

Comment: When i am trying to merge from master to testing using clearcase GUI getting the below error:

Comment: Needs Merge "M:\test_rel\test" [to \main\dev01_2013\CHECKEDOUT from \main\27 base \main\dev01_2013\8] ******************************** <<< directory 1: M:\test_rel\test@@\main\dev01_2013\8 >>> directory 2: M:\test_rel\test@@\main\27 >>> directory 3: M:\test_rel\test ******************************** -----[ directory 1 added directory 2 ]----- > test.txt --06-27T07:06 kum -----[ directory 1 added directory 3 ]----- > test.txt --07-01T07:34 kum merge: Error: *** No Automatic Decision Possible merge: Error: *** Aborting...

Comment: merge: Error: Unable to remove "C:\DOCUME~1\kum\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\tmp27813": Permission denied.
Directory merges were necessary and -depth was specified.
Unable to evaluate all possible merge candidates under those directories.
>>> Merge operation started: 7/2/2013 2:45:00 AM
********************************
<<< directory 1: M:\test_rel\test@@\main\dev01_2013\8
>>> directory 2: M:\test_rel\test@@\main\27
>>> directory 3: M:\test_rel\test
********************************

Comment: 3: M:\test_rel\test
********************************
-----------[ directory 1 ]-------------|---------[ added directory 2 ]---------
                                      -| test.txt  -+
-----------[ directory 1 ]-------------|---------[ added directory 3 ]---------
                                      -| test.txt  -+
merge: Error: *** No Automatic Decision Possible
merge: Error: *** Aborting...
merge: Error: Unable to remove "C:\DOCUME~1\kum\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\tmp27817": Permission denied.

Comment: @user2487946 that means you have done modifications in master since you have branches in testing, right?

Comment: I have added 3 new files in master unable to merge in branch

Comment: @user2487946 what ClearCase version are you using? And why do you have some "permission denied"?

Comment: ClearCase 7.1.1.9, I have full permissions on the vob and views too

Comment: @user2487946 sure but you have permission denied on files in temp: could you try your merge with all other applications closed in order to make sure one of them isn't keeping an handle on said temp file, preventing its deletion?

Comment: Tmp files which it was searching they are not available in the temp folder

Comment: @user2487946 sure, they must have been finally removed. But still, can you try again the merge with no other application opened?

Comment: The "Needs Merge" part is normal. Can you do the merge  through a gui?

Comment: I am trying to do from GUI, not much grep on command mode for me